# Is there a way to make Django report unit test errors as and when they occur?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Is there a tool/package to make Django report errors, perhaps to a socket or a file that can be tailed, as it goes through the tests. I hate to have to wait a good 15+ minutes for the whole test suite to be complete before seeing the failed tests. Particularly annoying when having upgraded Django, you find that a number of tests have errors.

Comment: Which tests are you talking about? Could you provide some more context?

Comment: You could run the tests with the [`--failfast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-failfast) option, which stops the tests and reports the failure immediately after a test fails. The disadvantage is that only see one failing test.

Comment: All the unit tests in my project. I have a few hundred of them. So after upgrading Django to 1.11, I hit 'manage.py test' and get a quite a number of errors, which I'm  fixing one by one. Issue is I get to see the errors only after  all the tests are run. The alternative is to run tests with the --failfast option and fix the first error as its reported.

Comment: @Alasdair That is what I do now. I'm also looking into TESTRUNNER docs to see if there are alternative implementations that can do what I described.

Comment: You can use the default command (manage.py test) with --parallel paramater, If you see any error in a particular app then concentrate on this app trying to fix the error (manage.py test my_broken_app)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pytest` along with `pytest-django` to run the tests instead, and use `maxfail` parameter to stop the tests after that many tests have failed.

```
py.test --maxfail=1 .    # in your code directory
```

[pytest-django documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Interesting. Similar to the `--failsafe` option. I'll look into it. Tks.